# AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'iter_cols'

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm new to openpyxl and writing a script to go through some columns and delete columns under multiple names. Every time I try to use `wb.iter_cols` it says:

```
workbook object has no attribute 'iter_cols'
```

I've checked the `openpyxl` version (3.0) and tried adding parameters to `iter_cols`, to no avail.

```py
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
wb.iter_cols()
DelCols()

def DelCols():
    for col in wb.iter_cols():
        if col == "StartDate" or col == "EndDate" or col == "Status" or col == "IPAddress"\
        or col == "Progress" or col == "Duration (in seconds)" or col == "Finished"\
        or col == "RecordedDate" or "ResponseId" or col == "RecipientLastName"\
        or col == "RecipientFirstName" or col == "RecipientEmail" or col == "ExternalReference"\
        or col == "LocationLatitude" or col == "LocationLongitude" or col == "DistributionChannel":
            wb.delete_cols(col)
```

Comment: Instead of editing the question to "solved" you can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) (although you have to wait 48 hours before you can mark it as accepted).

Answer (score 1):

Leaving this up in case someone else has the same problem as me.

- [`Worksheet.iter_cols`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html?highlight=iter_cols#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_cols)
- [`Worksheet.delete_cols`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html?highlight=iter_cols#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.delete_cols)

I had to change my code to:

```py
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(DocFileLocation)
ws = wb.active

def DelCols():
    for col in ws.iter_cols():
        if col == "StartDate" or col == "EndDate" or col == "Status" or col == "IPAddress"\
        or col == "Progress" or col == "Duration (in seconds)" or col == "Finished"\
        or col == "RecordedDate" or "ResponseId" or col == "RecipientLastName"\
        or col == "RecipientFirstName" or col == "RecipientEmail" or col == "ExternalReference"\
        or col == "LocationLatitude" or col == "LocationLongitude" or col == "DistributionChannel":
            ws.delete_cols(col)
```